# How to refresh Youtube Player View onItemClickListener() in a ListView

Tags: android, video, android-listview, youtube, youtube-api

I am able to play Youtube videos using `cuePlaylist()` but I also want to allow user to tap on any of the list item and then I want to refresh `YoutubePlayerView` with the video user just tapped

I am using `cuePlaylist()` so getting previous and next buttons as default functionality of Youtube player

So can I refresh `YoutubePlayerView` with the one I have selected in a `ListView`?

Here is my complete code, still when I do tap on any of the list item, not getting any change in `YoutubePlayerView` but able to `Log` video Id which I just clicked in a `ListView`...

```
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            strVideoID = flowerList.get(i).getUrl();
            Log.d("url:", strVideoID); // getting particular video id

            youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(API_KEY, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {

                // YouTubeプレーヤーの初期化成功
                @Override
                public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
                    if (!wasRestored) {
                        player.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);
                        player.loadVideo(strVideoID);
                        player.play();
                    }
                }

                // YouTubeプレーヤーの初期化失敗
                @Override
                public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult error) {
                    // YouTube error
                    String errorMessage = error.toString();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.d("errorMessage:", errorMessage);
                }
            });

        }
    });

    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {

        if (!b) {
            youTubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);
            youTubePlayer.cuePlaylist(PLAYLIST_ID);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Try with  strVideoID = flowerList.get(i-1).getUrl();   instead of  strVideoID = flowerList.get(i).getUrl();  Change i to i-1

Comment: @MaheshwarLigade but why because i am getting exact video id when i do tap on list item, the issue is I am not able to play the video which I have tapped in a List

Comment: I because array index is started from 0 to n  that’s why i think there should be issue with index. As of you mention in OP.

Comment: @sophie i am having same issue as yours can you help me please 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45530742/youtube-video-is-not-stopped-when-clicked-in-horizontallistview-item

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using the wrong approach here, you don't need to call initialize on `YoutubePlayerFragment` each time, the first initialization is enough which you done in onCreate method

```
YouTubePlayerFragment youTubePlayerFragment = YouTubePlayerFragment.newInstance();
    youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(API_KEY, this);
```

In the initialization listener you implemented in Activity, You should keep the reference of YoutubePlayer in a class level attribute like this

```
 //your class level attribute to keep reference of player
   YouTubePlayer mYoutubePlayer;

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {

    if (!b) {
        youTubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);
        youTubePlayer.cuePlaylist(PLAYLIST_ID);
        //Save reference of initialized player in class level attribute
         mYoutubePlayer = youTubePlayer;
    }

}
```

And use this player attribute to load videos inside onItemClick instead of calling initialize again on YoutubePlayerFragment with new listener

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

        strVideoID = flowerList.get(i).getUrl();
        Log.d("url:", strVideoID); // getting particular video id
        if(mYoutubePlayer!=null){
        mYoutubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);
        mYoutubePlayer.loadVideo(strVideoID);
        mYoutubePlayer.play();
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: thank you so much, now when I do tap on list item then its playing that particular video but not showing cuePlaylist functionality (my mean prev and next) this is the main concern for me. I have ticked your answer as useful but can't accept because I need cuePlaylist functionality.. How can I pass PLAYLIST_ID along with YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34260715/how-can-i-pass-video-id-along-with-playlist-id-in-cueplaylist

Comment: @Sophie although my answer resolves your current mentioned issue and the you also just used "player.loadVideo(strVideoID);" in your onItemClickListener, And the second issue you mentioned doesn't fall under it, I have also answered your second question.

Answer (score 0):

step to play any you tube video

1 create a you tube view  in xml file.

```
<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
                android:id="@+id/youtube_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />
```

2. inside java file

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements
               YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

           private static final int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;

           // YouTube player view
           private YouTubePlayerView youTubeView;

           @Override
           protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
               super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
               requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
               getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                       WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

               setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

               youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);

               // Initializing video player with developer key
               youTubeView.initialize(Config.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);

           }

           @Override
           public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                   YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
               if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
                   errorReason.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST).show();
               } else {
                   String errorMessage = String.format(
                           getString(R.string.error_player), errorReason.toString());
                   Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
           }

           @Override
           public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                   YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
               if (!wasRestored) {

                   // loadVideo() will auto play video
                   // Use cueVideo() method, if you don't want to play it automatically
                   player.loadVideo(YOUTUBE_VIDEO_CODE);

                   // Hiding player controls
                   player.setPlayerStyle(PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS);
               }
           }

           @Override
           protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
               if (requestCode == RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST) {
                   // Retry initialization if user performed a recovery action
                   getYouTubePlayerProvider().initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
               }
           }

           private YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
               return (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
           }

       }
   ```

Comment: ok r you using YouTubePlayerView to play a particular video  or using other view to play video ?

Comment: i download it  now i am able to see the video .

Comment: okay so do you have any kind of previous or next button in your video view default or are you adding custom previous or next button on video  view?