# How can i pass VIDEO_ID along with PLAYLIST_ID in cuePlaylist(...)

Tags: android, youtube

I am using `cuePlaylist()` so getting previous and next buttons as default functionality of Youtube player

I am also allowing user to tap on any of the list item (listview contains youtube playlist videos)

But when I am passing VIDEO_ID along with PLAYLIST_ID in that case I am getting `There was a problem with the network[400]`

```
 // PLAYLIST_ID : PLP7qPet500dfglA7FFTxBmB_snxCaMHDJ
 // strVideoID : 7OEprLI1rIM

 String sn = strVideoID+PLAYLIST_ID; 
 youTubePlayer.cuePlaylist(sn);
```

And using `loadVideo(...)` I am able to play that particular video but not getting PREV and NEXT buttons.

```
 youTubePlayer.loadVideo(strVideoID);
```

Comment: why it has been downvoted ? please let me know the reason

Comment: Sophie, for every Video or for some Videos?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK for all videos boss

Comment: But `strVideoID+PLAYLIST_ID` not valid PlaylistId. it is `PLAYLIST_ID `

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK yeah this is the main question how can I pass VideoID along with PlaylistID in cuePlaylist(..) and its possible because I have seen same functionality in one of the app published on Play Store...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always check the documentation first, https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer

I think following method can fit to your needs

```
loadPlaylist (String playlistId, int startIndex, int timeMillis)
```

Ref: https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer#loadPlaylist%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29

Comment: @Sophie as i don't have this scenario implemented so i didn't tested the method but from documentation it seems to fit for your scenario, can you share results of using mYoutubePlayer.loadPlaylist(PLAYLIST_ID, 7, 0); , what issue you face?

Comment: last and final issue, check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34329549/youtube-exit-full-screen-mode-textview-visibility-issue