# Exit Full Screen Video Mode on Back Press

Tags: java, android, android-video-player, onbackpressed

I just started with this [GMF](https://github.com/googleads/google-media-framework-android) example provided by Google.

I would like to know How can I Exit Full Screen Video Mode by doing tap on back button, I tried using below code, but did not get any success,

[here](https://github.com/googleads/google-media-framework-android/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/com/google/googlemediaframeworkdemo/demo/MainActivity.java) you can see the actual code of **MainActivity.java**

```
boolean isFullScreen = false; // globally declared

@Override
public void onGoToFullscreen() {
    isFullScreen = true;
    videoListView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}

@Override
public void onReturnFromFullscreen() {
    videoListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(isFullScreen) {
        onReturnFromFullscreen();
    }
    else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: what problem you are facing exactly. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have build your application around the [Demo](https://github.com/googleads/google-media-framework-android), in the Demo app you have the class `ImaPlayer` in package `com.google.googlemediaframeworkdemo.demo.adplayer`, which contains two `SimpleVideoPlayer` references, and as the name suggests one is for displaying adds and one is for displaying content.

> ```
>   /**
>    * Plays the ad.
>    */
>   private SimpleVideoPlayer adPlayer;
>
>  /**
>    * Plays the content (i.e. the actual video).
>    */
>   private SimpleVideoPlayer contentPlayer;
> ```

For exiting fullscreen you need to call setFullscreen(false) on [SimpleVideoPlayer](http://googleads.github.io/google-media-framework-android/docs/)

> ```
> public void setFullscreen(boolean shouldBeFullscreen)
>
> Make the player enter or leave fullscreen mode.
>
> Parameters:
>     shouldBeFullscreen - If true, the player is put into fullscreen mode. If false, the player leaves fullscreen mode.
> ```

Since both SimpleVideoPlayers are declared private you can not access them. Here are 2 solutions to solve this:

**Solution 1:**

In `ImaPlayer` class create getters for `adPlayer` and `contentPlayer`

```
public SimpleVideoPlayer getAdPlayer(){
    return this.adPlayer;
}

public SimpleVideoPlayer getContentPlayer(){
    return this.ContentPlayer;
}
```

In your `MainActivity` where you handle the back key press modify to this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(isFullScreen) {
        imaPlayer.getAdPlayer().setFullscreen(false);
        imaPlayer.getContentPlayer().setFullscreen(false);
        // after this calls you will see that your callback method onReturnFromFullscreen() will be called
    }
    else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

**Solution 2:**

In `ImaPlayer` class add this code:

```
public void exitFullscreen(){

 if (adPlayer != null) {
          adPlayer.setFullscreen(false);
        }
        contentPlayer.setFullscreen(false);
        //again after this calls you will see that your callback method onReturnFromFullscreen() will be called  
     }
 }
```

In case you have not build it around Demo application you need to call on your video player (which most likely is `SimpleVideoPlayer`) `setFullscreen(false)`

Comment: Have a look at this issue, please : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36055995/video-player-null-pointer-exception-using-google-media-framework-exoplayer

Comment: @Sophie I have responded there to your question.

Comment: check this please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36098317/onbackpressed-orientation-issue