# Video Player Null Pointer Exception using Google Media Framework Exoplayer

Tags: java, android, json, android-video-player, exoplayer

I am using [GMF](https://github.com/googleads/google-media-framework-android) sample to play Video in my app, where I am fetching video title and url from live JSON, here is the sample of my JSON :

```
{
"videos": [ 
{
"title":"Video 1",
"url":"88.mp4"
},
{
"title":"Video 2",
"url":"l5.mp4"
}
]}
```

And this is what my code looks like :

**MainActivity.java:**

```
  JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
  JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("videos");

  for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
       JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

       Videos video = new Videos();

       video.setTitle(object.getString("title"));
       video.setUrl(object.getString("url"));

       videosArrayList.add(video);
   }
```

Whenever, I do tap on any of the list item to play Video, getting `NPE`, see complete **Log**:

```
03-17 13:14:34.667 18799-18799/com.google.googlemediaframeworkdemo.demo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.google.googlemediaframeworkdemo.demo, PID: 18799
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.android.libraries.mediaframework.exoplayerextensions.RendererBuilderFactory.createRendererBuilder(RendererBuilderFactory.java:34)
at com.google.android.libraries.mediaframework.layeredvideo.LayerManager.<init>(LayerManager.java:78)
at com.google.android.libraries.mediaframework.layeredvideo.SimpleVideoPlayer.<init>(SimpleVideoPlayer.java:112)
at com.google.android.libraries.mediaframework.layeredvideo.SimpleVideoPlayer.<init>(SimpleVideoPlayer.java:81)
at com.google.googlemediaframeworkdemo.demo.adplayer.ImaPlayer.<init>(ImaPlayer.java:388)
at com.google.googlemediaframeworkdemo.demo.adplayer.ImaPlayer.<init>(ImaPlayer.java:434)
at com.google.googlemediaframeworkdemo.demo.adplayer.ImaPlayer.<init>(ImaPlayer.java:467)
at com.google.googlemediaframeworkdemo.demo.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:81)
at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1152)
at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3014)
at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3865)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-17 13:14:34.803 18799-18861/com.google.googlemediaframeworkdemo.demo D/dalvikvm: threadid=17: interp stack at 0x56eb0000
03-17 13:14:34.803 18799-18861/com.google.googlemediaframeworkdemo.demo D/dalvikvm: init ref table
03-17 13:14:34.803 18799-18861/com.google.googlemediaframeworkdemo.demo D/dalvikvm: init mutex
03-17 13:14:34.903 18799-18861/com.google.googlemediaframeworkdemo.demo D/MediatekClassFactory: createInstance(): Begin = 9861250
03-17 13:14:34.904 18799-18861/com.google.googlemediaframeworkdemo.demo D/MediatekClassFactory: create Instance with :  interface com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport
03-17 13:14:34.912 18799-18861/com.google.googlemediaframeworkdemo.demo W/MediatekClassFactory: Tablet not exist!, Get obj from default class
03-17 13:14:34.916 18799-18861/com.google.googlemediaframeworkdemo.demo D/MediatekClassFactory: create Instance from tablet library :  com.mediatek.tb.telephony.OnlyOwnerSimSupport
03-17 13:14:34.920 18799-18861/com.google.googlemediaframeworkdemo.demo D/MediatekClassFactory: createInstance(): End = 9861267
```

I wrote code as I think it should be, so may I know where I am missing ? what I am missing ? and how can i resolve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this part of the code

```
Videos video = new Videos();

video.setTitle(object.getString("title"));
video.setUrl(object.getString("url"));

videosArrayList.add(video);
```

you never assign the `video` field in `Videos` object `video` ( never call 
`public void setVideo(Video video) { this.video = video; }`). You use the default constructor p`ublic Videos() { }` which initializes the field `video` to `null`

To solve this issue add this line

```
video.setVideo(new Video(object.getString("url"),VideoType.MP4)))
```

Comment: I explained exactly the same to you Sophie, but may be you didn't understand my answer. Have a nice day :)

Comment: what if I would like to play Video by default when I do tap on List Item, like still I do tap on List Item > then I have to click on Play button in Video Player... now I want whenever user do tap on List Item then play video don't need to show Play button to play video...

Comment: Aren't you doing that already here `public void onItemClick(... imaPlayer.play(); ... `?

Answer (score 2):

When you fetch the response in your `doInBackgroud` method you create `Videos` objects and put title and url in its, but when you create your player you try get `Video` object when call `videosArrayList.get(i).getVideo()`, but it is never setted. In that point is your NullPointerException.

Comment: yes I did not understand your answer, but anyways I ticked your answer as useful... thank you