# onBackPressed() Orientation Issue

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest, android-orientation, exoplayer

`Activity` supports `Landscape` mode

```
   <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

where I have allocated 50% space to `Video Player` (using FrameLayout) and rest 50% to `ListView`.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/video_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/video_list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now, I have started *playing video* **>** *moved to full screen* mode **>** *pressed back to exit full screen* mode **>** *getting Activity in Portrait* mode (whereas I was **expecting to get it in Landscape** mode)

```
    boolean isFullScreen = false;

    @Override
    public void onGoToFullscreen() {
        isFullScreen = true;
        videoListView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReturnFromFullscreen() {
        videoListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Log.d("boolean:-", Boolean.toString(isFullScreen));
        if(isFullScreen) {
            imaPlayer.getContentPlayer().setFullscreen(false);
        }
        else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11310902/3790150

Answer (score 2, accepted):

/* I am not sure,can you put this line of code in on back pressed method ? */

```
Log.d("boolean:-", Boolean.toString(isFullScreen));
    if(isFullScreen) {
        imaPlayer.getContentPlayer().setFullscreen(false);
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    }
    else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Comment: Now when I click on back I am getting view in Landscape mode, but still when I do tap on button which comes in Video Player to exit full mode still getting in Portrait mode why ?

Comment: in onResume ()method put this line of code and check setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);