# Youtube Video is not Stopped when clicked in HorizontalListView Item

Tags: android, video, onclick, youtube-api

I am using Youtube Data API to Access the Video.I am successful on Displaying the thumbnail image on the ListView.When i start Application,and Click the one of List Item, it Loads on the container where the Video should b played.I got issue ,when i Click the next thumbnail image ,then next Video is not Displayed .I Checked on Log through the index ,the position are Changed but Video is not Loaded.I don't know where i am Doing Wrong?

this is same as mine problem but not able to solve looking this [How to refresh Youtube Player View onItemClickListener() in a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34017783/how-to-refresh-youtube-player-view-onitemclicklistener-in-a-listview)

**FragmentVideoDestination**

```
public class FragmentVideoDestination extends Fragment {

    private FragmentActivity myContext;

    YouTubePlayer YPlayer;
    private static final String YoutubeDeveloperKey = "AIzaSyCLk_SWbZseee8lpSEb6rLTSvhL8YSLjEE";
    String Navigation_URL_Popular_Destination_video = "http://192.168.100.7:1337/api/popular_destinations";
    HorizontalListView horizontalListView;
    FrameLayout framelayoutvideo;


    String video_Id;

    String thumbnail_image;
    String[] youtube_video_url;
    String parsed_url;
    ArrayList<ClassDestinationFragmentYoutubeVideo> destination_list_grid_vieo = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {

        if (activity instanceof FragmentActivity) {
            myContext = (FragmentActivity) activity;
        }

        super.onAttach(activity);
    }


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.destination_grid_detail_video, container, false);
//        YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerFragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();
//        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
//        transaction.replace(R.id.youtubeFragment, youTubePlayerFragment).commit();
        //youTubePlayerFragment = (YouTubePlayerSupportFragment) getSupport().findFragmentById(R.id.youtubeFragment);

////
        horizontalListView = (HorizontalListView) view.findViewById(R.id.horizontal_scroll_list_item);
        framelayoutvideo = (FrameLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.youtubeFragment);
        final YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerFragment = new YouTubePlayerSupportFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.relative_layout_destination_video, youTubePlayerFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();


        makeJsonPopularDestinationDetailPageVideo();


        horizontalListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                video_Id = destination_list_grid_vieo.get(position).getUrl();
                System.out.println("position" + destination_list_grid_vieo.get(position).getUrl());
                if (YPlayer != null) {
                    //YPlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);
                    YPlayer.loadVideo(video_Id);
                    //YPlayer.play();
                }


            }
        });


        youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(YoutubeDeveloperKey, new OnInitializedListener() {


            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {

                //youTubePlayer.setShowFullscreenButton(false);
                if (youTubePlayer != null) {
                    if (!b) {


                        // System.out.println("POsition" + destination_list_grid_vieo.get(0).getUrl());
                        //youTubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);
                        youTubePlayer.loadVideo(destination_list_grid_vieo.get(0).getUrl());
                        // youTubePlayer.loadVideo("Hc97uvxJTNQ");


                        YPlayer = youTubePlayer;
                        // youTubePlayer.play();

                    }
                }


            }


            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(Provider arg0, YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {
                String errorMessage = arg1.toString();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("errorMessage:", errorMessage);

            }


        });
















/*
        horizontalListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
                System.out.println("position" + destination_list_grid_vieo.get(position).getUrl());
                video_Id = destination_list_grid_vieo.get(position).getUrl();

             //   Picasso.with(getContext()).load(destination_list_grid.get(position).getOther_images()).into(imageViewPager);



                youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(YoutubeDeveloperKey, new OnInitializedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {

                        youTubePlayer.setShowFullscreenButton(false);

                        if (!b) {

                            youTubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);

                            youTubePlayer.cueVideo(video_Id); // youTubePlayer.play();
                            YPlayer = youTubePlayer;

                        }


                    }


                    @Override
                    public void onInitializationFailure(Provider arg0, YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {


                    }




                });

            }
        });   */


        return view;

    }


    private void makeJsonPopularDestinationDetailPageVideo() {

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        String URL1 = Navigation_URL_Popular_Destination_video + "/1";

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL1,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {


                            //
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

                            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();

                            jArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("videos");

                            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject jsonObjectinner = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                thumbnail_image = jsonObjectinner.getString("thumbnail");
                                //  youtube_video_url = jsonObjectinner.getString("url").substring(32, 43);
                                youtube_video_url = String.valueOf(jsonObjectinner.getString("url")).split("=");
                                parsed_url = youtube_video_url[1];


                                destination_list_grid_vieo.add(new ClassDestinationFragmentYoutubeVideo(thumbnail_image, parsed_url));
                                System.out.println("Destination list" + destination_list_grid_vieo.get(i).getUrl());
                            }


                            PopularDestinationGridVideAdapter popularDestinationGridVideAdapter = new PopularDestinationGridVideAdapter(getContext(), destination_list_grid_vieo);
//                            popularDestinationGridVideAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            System.out.println("Grid" + destination_list_grid_vieo);
                            horizontalListView.setAdapter(popularDestinationGridVideAdapter);


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Fetch failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), error.toString(), LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                //  headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                return headers;
            }

        };


        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        YPlayer = null;
    }
}
```

**PopularDestinationGridVideAdapter**

```
public class PopularDestinationGridVideAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context mContext;
    ArrayList<ClassDestinationFragmentYoutubeVideo> class_destination_youtube_video = null;
    String TAG = "HomeTab_adapter";


    public PopularDestinationGridVideAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<ClassDestinationFragmentYoutubeVideo> class_destination_youtube_video) {
        super();
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.class_destination_youtube_video = class_destination_youtube_video;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return class_destination_youtube_video.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return class_destination_youtube_video.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final Holder viewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            // inflate the layout
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            // LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_pager_popular_destination_item, parent, false);

            // well set up the ViewHolder
            //  viewHolder = new ClassScheduleStudentAdapter.Holder();
            viewHolder = new Holder();

            // viewHolder.popular_destintion_id = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.student_profile_subject);
            viewHolder.view = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_detail_page_item);


            //     Log.d(TAG, "@@ postion:" + position + " getTeacherName" + class_destination.get(position).getId());
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);


        } else {
            // we've just avoided calling findViewById() on resource everytime
            // just use the viewHolder
            //  viewHolder = (ClassScheduleStudentAdapter.Holder) convertView.getTag();
            viewHolder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        //  File f = new File(class_destination.get(position).getImagelogo());
        // Picasso.with(mContext).load(f).into(viewHolder.image_logo);

        Picasso.with(mContext).load(class_destination_youtube_video.get(position).getThumbnai()).error(R.drawable.close).into(viewHolder.view);

        return convertView;
    }

    class Holder {
        ImageView view;
    }


}
```

**log**

```
08-10 10:29:46.708 16772-16772/org.municipality.mobile.patanheritage E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                       Process: org.municipality.mobile.patanheritage, PID: 16772
                                                                                       java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
                                                                                           at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
                                                                                           at org.municipality.mobile.patanheritage.fragment.FragmentVideoDestination$2.onInitializationSuccess(FragmentVideoDestination.java:139)
                                                                                           at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                                           at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView$1.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                                           at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r.g(Unknown Source)
                                                                                           at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$c.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                                           at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$b.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                                           at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

> List Item index are shown changed in the Log but the Running Video is not stopped and Start the New Video When CLicked in the Another List Item Video.How can this issue be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class FragmentVideoDestination extends Fragment {
    private FragmentActivity myContext;
    YouTubePlayer YPlayer;
    private static final String YoutubeDeveloperKey = "AIzaSyCLk_SWbZseee8lpSEb6rLTSvhL8YSLjEE";
    String Navigation_URL_Popular_Destination_video = "http://192.168.100.7:1337/api/popular_destinations";
    HorizontalListView horizontalListView;
    FrameLayout framelayoutvideo;
    String video_Id;
    String thumbnail_image;
    String[] youtube_video_url;
    String parsed_url;
    ArrayList<ClassDestinationFragmentYoutubeVideo> destination_list_grid_vieo = new ArrayList<>();
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.destination_grid_detail_video, container, false);
        horizontalListView = (HorizontalListView) view.findViewById(R.id.horizontal_scroll_list_item);
        framelayoutvideo = (FrameLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.youtubeFragment);
        final YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerFragment = new YouTubePlayerSupportFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
       fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.relative_layout_destination_video, youTubePlayerFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        makeJsonPopularDestinationDetailPageVideo();
        horizontalListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                video_Id = destination_list_grid_vieo.get(position).getUrl();
                System.out.println("position" + destination_list_grid_vieo.get(position).getUrl());
                if (YPlayer != null) {
                     YPlayer.cueVideo(video_Id); // youTubePlayer.play();
                }
            }
        });
        youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(YoutubeDeveloperKey, new OnInitializedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
        if (!b) {
             YPlayer= youTubePlayer;
            if(video_Id!=null)
                         YPlayer.cueVideo(video_Id);
                    }
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(Provider arg0, YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {

            }

        });
        return view;

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    if (YPlayer!= null) {
            YPlayer.release();
            YPlayer  = null;
        }
    }

    private void makeJsonPopularDestinationDetailPageVideo() {

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        String URL1 = Navigation_URL_Popular_Destination_video + "/1";

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL1,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {


                            //
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

                            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();

                            jArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("videos");

                            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject jsonObjectinner = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                thumbnail_image = jsonObjectinner.getString("thumbnail");
                                //  youtube_video_url = jsonObjectinner.getString("url").substring(32, 43);
                                youtube_video_url = String.valueOf(jsonObjectinner.getString("url")).split("=");
                                parsed_url = youtube_video_url[1];
                                destination_list_grid_vieo.add(new ClassDestinationFragmentYoutubeVideo(thumbnail_image, parsed_url));
                                System.out.println("Destination list" + destination_list_grid_vieo.get(i).getUrl());
                            }


                            PopularDestinationGridVideAdapter popularDestinationGridVideAdapter = new PopularDestinationGridVideAdapter(getContext(), destination_list_grid_vieo);
                video_Id=destination_list_grid_vieo.get(0).getUrl();
                if(YPlayer!=null){
                YPlayer.cueVideo(video_Id);
                }
//                            popularDestinationGridVideAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            System.out.println("Grid" + destination_list_grid_vieo);
                            horizontalListView.setAdapter(popularDestinationGridVideAdapter);


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Fetch failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), error.toString(), LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                //  headers.put("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                return headers;
            }
        };
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

This might help you

Comment: just a minute i will implement it

Answer (score 1):

you are initializing the player everytime your list item is clicked. It should be done only once and you don't have to use 
 youTubePlayer.play();
following line will work
youTubePlayer.cueVideo(video_Id);

Comment: same result. item with position 2 is not shown..Position changes but video is not shown

I/System.out: position1zZTfnwLhYU
I/System.out: positionM6Ae0H7OdRU
I/System.out: positionM6Ae0H7OdRU
I/System.out: positionM6Ae0H7OdRU
I/System.out: position1zZTfnwLhYU

Comment: are you pulling the video from youtube?

Comment: horizontalListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
                System.out.println("position" + destination_list_grid_vieo.get(position).getUrl());
                video_Id = destination_list_grid_vieo.get(position).getUrl();
 youTubePlayer.cueVideo(video_Id);
        });